# insert a VF Page calling a wrapper class on s Standard Page Layout

Tags: apex, visualforce

Use Case:

On a detail page of a page layout (my_object__c), i want to display a a list of records, and allow this user to choose 2 of those records, then click a button to go to a new VF page, if the user selects more than 2, i want him to get a notification of some kind saying you need to select 2 records, I do not want the page refeshed though.

Strategy:

In order to get the checkboxes, I'm using a wrapper class, like this: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class and i have that part going by creating a custonm controller...  And when I do a custom controller, I can't put it on that stabdard page layout for my_object__c

Comment: You could make it an extension and that should let you drop the VF page into the standard page layout.

Comment: You are looking at handling that on the front-end by Javascript or JQuery. Once the onclick function is executed on the input button, from the JS you can call an `apexFunction` that will redirect the user to the other page if necessary. If you need more guidance, edit your question and provide pieces of your code.

Comment: Are these related records? If so, a standard related list with a custom js list button would do the trick. Or is there a reason the list must be embedded in a VF field on the page layout?

Comment: @tim these are related detail records in a mdr relationship...?

Comment: @nivyaj Although this question was marked as a duplicate, my thought is that VF + custom wrapper is overkill for what you are trying to do. I've outlined a simpler approach in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are related records, I think your best bet is to do the following:

1. On the detail object in your mdr, create a custom button. Under Display Type, choose "List button" and be sure that "Display Checkboxes (for Multi-Record Selection)" is selected. For "Behavior" choose "Execute Javascript" and for "Content Source" choose "OnClick Javascript"
2. In the text area, use something similar to the following. In this example, I'm creating the button on the contact object and displaying it on the account page layout in the contact related list. Just replace Contact below with whatever your related object is. Also, replace the redirectUrl with whatever your VF page is:

   ```
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
   var recordIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Contact)}; //Replace Contact with your related object (e.g. my_related_object__c)
   var redirectUrl = '/apex/mycustompage'; //replace with your custom VF page

   if (recordIds.length == 2) {
       //redirect the user
       parent.location.href = redirectUrl+'?id1='+recordIds[0]+'&id2='+recordIds[1];
   } else { 
       //alert if they didn't select 2 records
       alert("Please select at least one record to update.");
   }
   ```

   This will throw an alert window if they don't select 2 records (without refreshing the page) and will redirect them if they do. In the redirect, I'm passing in the record ids as url parameters (id1 and id2) to be handled in your VF controller.
3. Add the custom button to the page layout of your master object in the mdr in the related list for your related object.

Comment: my only regret is that I can't approve this answer ten times. This was very helpful!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The standard controller is what allows you embed a page on a page layout. Page layouts are bound to objects, we don't let you add a Visualforce page to that page layout without it also being bound to the primary object of that page.

Standard controller with a custom extension class will work in this scenario.